# Dropzone - Server responded with 0 code

Tags: ssh, apache2, dropzone.js, symfony-3.1, angular-seed

**Ubuntuu - ssh - Symfony3 - Angular-seed - Dropzone**

I'm working on a task which upload a excel file from dropzone to a web service realized with symfony3. 
When the uploading is finished, the web-service start to parsing file in order to return a success for the dorpzone's success event, which is waiting for a signal from the php-part of the result of parsing.

I'm in the deployment phase, and working with the ssh-server of my client.
Everythings work fine (upload , parsing , return success message) when i run my web-service with

> php bin/console server:start *myserverurl:port*

but when i use a virtual-host created by the client, there's the issue now :

after uploding file, immediately i got the dropzone's error "***Server responded with 0 code.***" but the file has been got by the web-service and the process is successfully completed, of course it tried to return the successful end-message to dropzone, but it's already down.
I have been tested files with those sizes (2.4M / 8.9M / 14.5M).

In contrary, everything work well with some file (207K / 50K).

I can't conclude if this problem due to a extern parameter (apache-limit, ...), i'm not sure if the server block the waiting event of dropzone because of time-limit or something else.

This is my dropzone configuration :

```
$scope.dropzoneConfig = {
            'options': { // passed into the Dropzone constructor
                'url': $rootScope.baseUrl + 'admin/surveys/updates?access_token=' + $auth.getToken(),
                'maxFiles': 1,
                'uploadMultiple': false,
                'autoProcessQueue': false,
                'maxFileSize': 30
            },
            'eventHandlers': {
                'addedfile': function (file) {
                    if (!$scope.dropzone) {
                        $scope.dropzone = this;
                    }

                    if (!(vm.allowedExt.indexOf(vm.getFileExt(file.name)) > -1 )) {
                        $scope.resetForm();
                        vm.showErrorAlert('L\'extension de votre fichier est invalide , SVP veuilez choisir une extension .xlsx ou .xls');
                        return;
                    }

                    if ($scope.surveyCreate) {
                        if ($scope.surveyCreate.$valid) {
                            vm.enableBtn();
                        } else {
                            vm.disableBtn();
                        }
                    }

                    // survey edit
                    if ($scope.surveyEdit && $scope.selectedSurvey != undefined) {
                        vm.enableBtn();
                    }

                },
                'maxfilesexceeded': function (file) {
                    this.removeAllFiles();
                    this.addFile(file);
                },
                'sending': function (file, xhr, formData) {
                    if ($scope.survey != undefined && $scope.survey.name) {
                        formData.append('name', $scope.survey.name);
                    }

                    if ($scope.selectedSurvey != undefined) {
                        formData.append('survey_id', $scope.selectedSurvey.id);
                    }
                },
                'success': function (file, response) {
                    vm.hideSpinner();
                    $scope.resetForm();
                    if (response.success) {
                        vm.showSuccessAlert();
                        $scope.updateSurveysArray(response.data);
                    } else {
                        vm.showErrorAlert(response.errorMsg);
                    }
                },
                "error": function (file, error, xhr) {
                    vm.hideSpinner();
                    $scope.resetForm();
                    if (error.hasOwnProperty('message'))
                        vm.showErrorAlert(error.message);
                    else
                        vm.showErrorAlert('file transfer error');
                }
            }
        };
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? I get the same problem too randomly, but somehow only with IOS clients. If I attempt to attach a new file just before a response is received from a previous ajax upload, that previous request will error out (eventhough my server processed the request just fine). Apache log shows a 200 success response. Nginx though shows a 499, leading me to think that the IOS client (tested with Safari and Chrome) just closes the connection before receiving a response.

Answer (score 1):

first check php.ini and check is upload_max_filesize if it small than make it 1000M

add event listener on submit button :

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (file) {

```
    if (myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().length > 0) {
        if (submitfiles === true) {
            submitfiles = false;
            return;
        }

        file.preventDefault();
        myDropzone.processQueue();

        myDropzone.on("complete", function () {
            submitfiles = true;
            $('#submit_button').trigger('click');
        });
    } 
});
```